# Which version of H263 does libavcodec support?

Tags: ffmpeg, codecs

Which version of H263 does libavcodec support?

I'm looking for H263 2000 (v3/H263++) support, but I can't verify anywhere
that that's what being supported.

Answer (score 1):

Since [FFmpeg official documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#SEC6) (libavcodec is part of ffmpeg) states that only these versions of H263 are supported:

> 1. H.263 / H.263-1996
> 2. H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2

I think it would be a fair shot to presume that H263++ isn't supported by libavcodec (the official docs don't include it). To be 100% sure, I'd check it traditional way - download libavcodec and try to use it with a sample H263++ video ;)

BTW - I think this question belongs to superuser.

Comment: Thanks.
From what I've read H.264+ and H.264++ isn't vary different. 

Regarding: superuser/serverfault, I'm always confused about which to use, for what I care they all could be merge and filtered by tags instead.